# wxPython - HyperTreeList Item BackgoundColour doesn't apply to full row

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I am using HyperTreeList rom wxPython to Manage some data.

In the Documentation it says that this style:

```
wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT    
Use this style to have the background colour and the selection highlight extend over the entire horizontal row of the tree control window.
```

Will apply the Item Backgroundcolour to the complete row. Which does not happen on my machine.
What am i missing here?

Example code to test with:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.hypertreelist as HTL

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="HyperTreeList Demo")

        tree = HTL.HyperTreeList(self, agwStyle= HTL.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT)
        tree.AddColumn("Tree Column", width=200)
        tree.AddColumn("Column 1", width=200, flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        root = tree.AddRoot("Root")

        parent = tree.AppendItem(root, "First child")
        tree.SetItemText(parent, "Child of root", column=1)
        
        tree.SetItemBackgroundColour(parent, "#AFAFAF") 



# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_DEFAULT)
frame = MyFrame()
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug -> https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2081
See my fix in hypertreelist.py.
I hope it will be fixed in one of the next versions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30831631)